# Referencing Files from the Cloud

Tags: php, mysql, cloud

I asked a question earlier about the difference between cloud apps and web apps, and the answers and links I received made me to believe that 'cloud' is more of a location of an application, and not just about specific applications. And that prompts these questions: 
1) If I'm developing an application that'll be based in the cloud using PHP and MySQL; traditional server setups requires me to have a PHP and MySQL engines on the server; otherwise, they won't run. Is it the same with the cloud? Do I have to look for clouds with these engines, install them myself, or they aren't needed at all? 
2) When building applications, files are usually referenced relatively or absolutely, based on their location to the calling file. With the cloud, since you don't know the location of the files, how can you reference the required files? Do you have to use URLs for that? 
I've pored over many of the cloud questions on here, and it seems that there are a lot of confused souls out there just like myself, and most of the answers don't seem too convincing. Hence, my reason for asking again. 
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The *cloud* doesn't mean you don't know the location of your files, it only means that the files are not stored on the end user's computer (possibly).  From your perspective as the developer of the web application, you still will (indeed *must*) know the locations of any stored files, since it is your application storing them.

To give your end user a reference URL to a file, you can do many different things. One method, for example, involves storing some kind of unique identifier along with the file path to a stored file on your server together in a database. You give the user a URL that references the unique identifier, and in your code you then retrieve the file from disk and stream it down to the user using the correct headers.

Another method is to store files in the database as binary BLOBs, and retrieve the data and send it down to the browser with the correct headers. Again, you as the application developer are still responsible for the fate of those files, even though the end user doesn't need to worry about where or how they're stored.

Comment: and does the cloud require language engines such as PHP or MySQL engine before the application can be run? If so, there's really only one difference between a server and a cloud, if they both allow you to perform the same operations, the only difference being that servers' cost more than cloud.

Comment: @user705339 "The cloud" has no real definition - it's just a marketing term most used by software & hosting providers.  In common usage, it refers to something like the Amazon EC2 cloud, which is really just servers that you don't have to purchase and manage yourself, as Amazon handles it all for you.  So to answer your question, yes it still requires web servers, scripting engines like PHP, and everything else you would normally have on a server. You just don't have to purchase the hardware, install the OS, or manage the hardware & network, as that's done for you by the host.

Comment: Thanks very much for the clarification, Michael. Does that mean that purchasing dedicated servers for high traffic sites are no longer necessary? Put your comments as answers, so I can mark them as the answer